# Thorough setuptools installation help (Mac)

Tags: python, installation, setuptools

I am learning python with no programming experience, from a textbook. It asked me to install setup tools, which I downloaded. However, whenever I try to install it through terminal as the website says, I get the following message:
    error:

```
can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

[Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.5/lib/python2.5/site-packages/test-easy-install-2960.write-test'
```

I think I am doing something wrong on my part however I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I am running python 2.5, and i have downloaded setuptools 2.5 (the textbook asked for these specific versions).I have only gotten as far as downloading the setup tools file to my desktop. Can somebody please provide extremely thorough and easy instructions about how to install setup tools? I am running Mac OS X Mountain Lion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have permission to install to this folder, likely because the command should be run as root (using `sudo`).

---

Alternatively, you might want to look into [homebrew](https://brew.sh), which is a package manager for Mac OS. If you install Python through homebrew, it will come bundled with distutils and pip, which is all you should need.

And will be a more up-to-date version of Python too!

Comment: He's already got a more up-to-date version of Python—Mountain Lion comes with 2.7.2—and has apparently chosen to run 2.5 anyway for some reason. So installing another 2.7 isn't going to do him much good. Meanwhile, half the problems Mac users have with Python configuration on SO are because they have two different copies of the same Python version and don't understand the intricacies of keeping them straight; I think it's a very bad idea to encourage even more novices to do the same thing.

Comment: I just used sudo and it installed when I used the non-root password. It said the root password was incorrect, even though it was not. It worked though so thanks for the advice! I entered `sudo sh setuptools-0.6c11-py2.5.egg`

Comment: @user1947112: With `sudo`, you type your _own_ password, not the root password. (It's a bit more complicated than that. There's a special file called `/etc/sudoers` that lets you set up all kinds of complex things. But the defaults that come with OS X say, in effect, that anyone who's an Admin user can run any program as root by doing `sudo program` and typing their own password.)

Answer (score 2):

First, the Python 2.5, 2.6, and 2.7 versions that come with Mountain Lion already have setuptools and/or distribute, so you don't need to do anything at all here. However, you are going to run into the same problem again later, so:

If you want to install anything into the system-wide site-packages, you need to use `sudo` to do that, because otherwise you don't have write access. For example:

```
sudo python2.5 setup.py install
```

I'm also curious why you're using `python2.5` instead of `python2.7` (or just `python`, which is the same thing). There are not many libraries and programs out there that will work with 2.5 but not with 2.7, and unless you specifically need one of those programs, you should stick with 2.7. (And if you follow this advice, you can drop the `2.5` and `-2.5` suffixes on everything that follows.)

Meanwhile, all three versions of Python have `easy_install` already configured, so you very rarely need to download something and install it manually; you can just do `sudo easy_install-2.5 foo` instead. However, `pip` is even better than `easy_install`, except for a very small handful of packages—most notably `pip` itself, of course. So, the first thing you should do is:

```
sudo easy_install-2.5 pip
```

Then, whenever you need to install package `foo` in the future:

```
sudo pip-2.5 install foo
```

Many people are eager to suggest installing other versions of Python—Homebrew, MacPorts, Python.org, Enthought, or ActiveState. Do not do this. It was usually necessary back in the days of Tiger (10.4), because Apple used to distribute incomplete or broken Python versions, but this has not been true for a long time. And it means you will end up with two copies of `python2.7`/`python`, two copies of `easy_install-2.7`/`easy_install`, and, worst of all, a single copy of `pip-2.7`/`pip` (whichever one you install later will erase the older one). I guarantee you will not keep them straight, and you will be back here with new questions about "I installed package foo and it succeeded, but now I can't import it".

However, if you want Python 3, then I would definitely recommend installing *that* from Homebrew or Python.org. There is no Apple-installed 3.x version, and Python 2.x and 3.x generally stay out of each others' ways (e.g., you get `python3` instead of just `python`).

Comment: I'm using Python 2.5 because book I'm using, _Practical Programming: An Introduction to Computer Science Using Python_, recommended it. For now I'll just stick with Python 2.5 because that is what I already have installed. In the future I'll check online first.

Comment: @user1947112: Again, Mountain Lion comes with 2.5, 2.6, and 2.7 all pre-installed. If you installed _another_ 2.5, you're going to confuse yourself; it's much easier to use the pre-installed version. (Which, again, already has `setuptools`, and `easy_install-2.5` is ready to go for everything else—or, ideally, just for `pip`.)